# The scrollview view is useless

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have trouble adding scroll view to my layout. What shall I do?

error says : 
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - This ScrollView view is useless (no children, no background, no id, no style)
    - The element type "Scrollview" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

```
<Scrollview xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>






<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="کد اطلاعات عمومی گوشی" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="کد فکتوری ریست گوشی بدون از بین بردن اپلیکیشن ها" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="کد فکتوری ریست کلی" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="اطلاعات دوربین" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="تغییر عملکرد دکمه power/end call" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="پشتیبان گیری از فایل ها(عکس ها ، یادداشت ها و...)" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="انجام تست و تنظیم بعضی از تنطیمات گوشی" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="کد تست های سخت افزاری" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</ScrollView>
</Scrollview>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

pls correct the code. Thanks for advance

Comment: you should also better use strings.xml to get your texts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New layout:

```
<Scrollview
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="?? ??????? ????? ????"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="?? ?????? ???? ???? ???? ?? ??? ???? ???????? ??"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="?? ?????? ???? ???"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="??????? ??????"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="????? ?????? ???? power/end call"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="??????? ???? ?? ???? ??(??? ?? ? ??????? ?? ?...)"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="????? ??? ? ????? ???? ?? ??????? ????"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="?? ??? ??? ??? ??????"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Button"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Button"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</Scrollview>
```

Comment: And then he's going to run into the error "ScrollView can only have one child" so the solution should also be to remove the closing brackets on the first LinearLayout and add them right before the closing brackets on the ScrollView.

Comment: and one other thing, sometimes when I change the layout code everything in the package gets an error. It underlines the r in (R.xxxx.xxxxx) and when I import the r, it underlines the layout name. What shal i do?

Comment: Said in this way it's a bit hard to understand. I guess that there is some unclosed **>**? or some unclosed **/>** or something else which is misspelled, such as "SrollView" instead of "ScrollView"?

Answer (score 2):

ScrollView can only take one child view. What you need to do is put your views like all the buttons in a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout view and then add a scrollView.

Answer (score 1):

A ScrollView can only contain a single child, hence you need to have something like this:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <Button />
        <Button />
        <Button />
        <Button />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

You also have a bunch of close tags at the end which you should get rid of:

```
</Scrollview>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```